# how to find my device OID

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

i use this command

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c<Group-Name> <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>
```

and see result like this

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.6.2 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.6.3 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.6.4 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.7.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.7.2 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.7.3 = INTEGER: 3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.7.4 = INTEGER: 4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.8.1 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.8.2 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.8.3 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.8.4 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.9.1 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.9.2 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.9.3 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.8.1.9.4 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.1.0 = INTEGER: 4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
```

how i can find what is this OID for ? i use this command

```
snmptranslate iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.1.0
```

but the answer is

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.1.0
```

how can i see OID device as human readable ?

Comment: You need HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the path to the MIBs.
You can see which paths are referenced via ...

```
 net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs
/Users/<home>/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
```

There are various ways in net-snap to provide path to MIBs 
look at [Using and loading MIBs](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS)  on net-snmp site

When path set up you should see this ....

```
$ snmptranslate iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.1.0
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWOSIndex.0
```

And for my setup ...

```
$ grep HOST-RESOURCES-MIB /usr/share/snmp/mibs/*| grep DEFINITIONS 
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.txt:HOST-RESOURCES-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
```

Comment: Tanks for your help